# Use Omnifaces in Pac4j during using AuthorizationGenerator

Tags: omnifaces, pac4j

I´m trying to load after successful authentication from Keycloak (AUTH provider) some information and store in my `@SessionScoped` Bean and set it in the `Session Attribute` from Omnifaces.

In shiro.ini I defined this line:

```
roleAdminAuthGenerator = de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator
oidcClient.authorizationGenerator = $roleAdminAuthGenerator
```

This is my `Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator` class:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.omnifaces.util.Beans;
import org.pac4j.core.authorization.generator.AuthorizationGenerator;
import org.pac4j.core.context.WebContext;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;
import org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import de.dpunkt.myaktion.user.controller.login.LoginBean;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator implements AuthorizationGenerator {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator.class);

    public Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator() {
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserProfile> generate(final WebContext context, final SessionStore sessionStore,
            final UserProfile profile) {

        try {

            final LoginBean loginBean = Beans.getReference(LoginBean.class);

            String username = profile.getUsername();

            loginBean.submitPac4j(username);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }

        return Optional.of(profile);
    }

}
```

Using CDI is working via:

```
Beans.getReference(LoginBean.class)
```

In my LoginBean I got always a NPE for:

```
public void submitPac4j(String username)  {
    Faces.setSessionAttribute("myuser", new Object());
}
```

Because the `Faces Context` is NULL.
-> In Omnifaces class "FacesLocal" this "context" is NULL
[image]

How can I fix this?